# Reducing $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty\ a^nb^m$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to reduce the following nested summation (removing all summations), using the **fact** that: $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\ a^i = \frac{1}{1- a}$.

*Problem*: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty\ a^nb^m$$

I know that if instead of $m=n$ in the summation, we had $m=0$, it would be easy to reduce.  I'd just use the above **fact** twice.  How could I reduce this *problem*, removing all summations, using the above fact?

Note: Although this IS related to a homework assignment, you are welcome to post a final answer.  This is just some algebra that's a part of a much larger probability question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know the general formula for the sum of a geometric series that doesn't start at $0$, you can do this

$$\sum_{m=n}^\infty b^m=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^{n+k}=b^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^k=\frac{b^n}{1-b}$$

to derive it.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
$$\sum_{m=n}^\infty a^nb^m=a^n\sum_{m=n}^\infty b^m = a^n\sum_{m=n}^\infty (b^n)(b^{m-n})=a^nb^n\sum_{m=n}^\infty b^{m-n}=a^nb^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty b^k.$$